# Реклама в Unity

Tags: unity3d, admob, реклама

В процессе разработки игры, дошел до этапа, когда нужно добавить рекламу. Я в этом деле новичок, поэтому обращаюсь к опытным Unity игроделам:

1. Какие рекламные площадки на подобии AdMob вы можете порекомендовать? (Unity Ads мы не берем ибо оттуда деньги вывести невозможно)
2. Могу ли я использовать несколько рекламных площадок например AdMob с какой-нибудь другой площадкой (не забанят ли игру/приложение в маркете?)
3. Есть ли сервисы с видео рекламой на подобии Unity Ads?
4. Самый главный вопрос: Если использовать 2-3 площадки показа рекламы то каким образом лучше выводить рекламу? Рандом или какой-то алгоритм... Ваши мысли.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Можно использовать все что на целевой платформе будет работать. Видео рекламы хватает, но нимально читайте условия. Если использовать несколько сразу сеток то нужен медиатор https://hsto.org/files/e24/07a/236/e2407a23620947028b65d67a0dac6ca2.png вот блок схема с хабра. Ну это чтобы понимали масштаб работы. Можно конечно сделать проще и взять сдк в которой все это интегрированы. Вопрос - оффтоп

Comment: предложу вам использовать  [applovin](http://applovin.com) - очень просто добавлять, есть полная документация!

Answer (score 3):

За несколько рекламных площадок не забанят.
Можно использовать http://www.appodeal.ru.
Автоматическая медиация рекламных сетей. Нужно зарегистрироваться только в нем и admob. Деньги выводятся через appodeal.

Comment: Точнее все сети, кроме admob выводятся через appodeal

Comment: Благодарю. Правильно ли я понимаю, что appodeal сам рандомно будет рекламу из нескольких источников подставлять?